# Find projection matrix using partitioned matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, projection-matrices

If X is a *($n$, $p+1$)* design matrix, partition $X$ to be $X$=[$J$ $X$*]  where $J$ is a *($n$,$1$)* vector of all $1$'s, and $X$* is a *($n$,$p$)* matrix.

Let $H_X$ be a projection matrix, where $H_X$ = $X{(X'X)}^{-1}X'$.

I'm trying to prove:

> $H_X$ = $H_J$ + $H_X*$

And in doing so, I've been trying to deduce the above equation using:

> Suppose the design matrix $X$ can be decomposed by columns as $X$= [$A$ $B$]. 
>   Define the hat or projection operator as $P${$X$} = $X{(X'X)}^{-1}X'$.
>   Similarly, define the residual operator as $M${$X$}=$I$-$P${$X$}. 
>   Then the projection matrix can be decomposed as follows:
>
> $P${$X$} = $P${$A$} + $P${$M${$A$}$B$}.

I found this formula (the "Blockwise Formula") on Wikipedia.
The link is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix

I've been trying to prove this formula, and from that deduce the equation I'm trying to solve. But I still haven't found a way to prove either.

How can I prove the equation above?

Will the formula I found on Wikipedia be helpful?

Comment: This formula will only work if the columns of $J$ are perpendicular to the columns of $X^*$.  That is, if $J'X^* = 0$. In other words, all columns of $X^*$ should have entries that sum to $0$.

Comment: Oh okay..so the "Blockwise Formula" won't be helpful then.. Thanks alot! So in this case do you happen to have any ideas on how I might solve the above equation?? @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter-example: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
You can check that in this case $H_X=I_4 \neq H_J + H_{X^*}$.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I found out the equation I was trying to solve was flawed in the first place: It was H(X)=H(J) + H([I-H(J)]X*)...! The Blockwise Formula works in this case when X, J, X* are all full rank. Thanks alot for your suggestions:)